# Elasticsearch - Update a field of several records already indexed based on a value from a new record still not indexed

Tags: elasticsearch, processor, elasticsearch-painless, ingest, update-by-query

I need to update a field of several records already indexed based on a value from a new record still not indexed. Is there any way to implement it?

The table below describes my index with current docs. The yellow line would be a new doc arriving.

RULE: As far the latest entry is received (NEW “not indexed entry”) with STATE=OFF, all respective entries of Group 1 (FROM EXISTING INDEX) must be set COLOR=RED

[image: Table with sample data]

Could you please let me know any example how to implement?

Thanks

Marcelo

Comment: Is this new message intercepted at application level from where you can run update_by_query ?

Comment: Sahil, there will be a kafka connector pushing data to elasticsearch. I am wondering know at this moment if a logstash addition between both components would allow me to deliver this solution. What do you think about?